RouterView is not working in the vue project
I am working on a vue-project. I am having a Home page on which I had a sideBar component and a routerView component.
It looks like this

On clicking any item of the sidebar, the router pushes to a respective path of that page defined in navigateToRoute() fn in Home.vue. But the components are not rendered through the router-view due to which when redirection happens , the sidebar on the left disappears .  Similar thing happens for other menuItems

Below is the code for Home.vue and router/index.js ( where routes are defined) .
Home.vue
<template>
  <div class="landing-page">
     <categoryPage v-if="menuItemRendered === 'category'" />

    <sidebar @menuItemSelected="navigateToRoute"/>


    <RouterView />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
 /* eslint-disable */

/* File imports */

import sidebar from "@/components/sidebar.vue";
import categoryPage from "@/pages/category-page.vue";


/* Util imports */
import { getCompany } from "@/helper/utils";


import { RouterView } from "vue-router";

export default {
  name: "LandingPage",
  components: {
    
    sidebar,
    
  },
  data() {
    return {
      applications_list: [],
      all_applications: [],
      pageLoading: false,
      menuItemRendered: 'category',
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchApplications();
    //console.log(MainService.getDepartments());
  },
  methods: {
    
    handleMenuItemSelected(menuItem) {
      console.log("Selected Menu Item: ", menuItem);
      this.menuItemRendered = menuItem;
    },
    navigateToRoute(menuItem) {
      console.log("Selected Menu Item: ", menuItem);
      switch(menuItem) {
        case 'category':
          this.$router.push(`${getCompany()}/category`);
          break;
        case 'subCategory':
          this.$router.push(`${getCompany()}/subCategory`);
          break;
        case 'product':
          this.$router.push(`${getCompany()}/product`);
          break;
        case 'vendor':
          this.$router.push(`${getCompany()}/vendor`);
          break;
        case 'vendorHoliday':
          this.$router.push(`${getCompany()}/vendorHoliday`);
          break;
        case 'brand':
          this.$router.push(`${getCompany()}/brand`);
          break;
        case 'tags':
          this.$router.push(`${getCompany()}/tags`);
          break;
        case 'productTagMapping':
          this.$router.push(`${getCompany()}/productTagMapping`);
          break;
        case 'fvStickers':
          this.$router.push(`${getCompany()}/fvStickers`);
          break;
        case 'productStickers':
          this.$router.push(`${getCompany()}/productStickers`);
          break;
        default:
          this.$router.push(`${getCompany()}/`)
      }
    }
  },
};
</script>

router/index.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';

import CategoryPage  from '../pages/category-page.vue';
import subCategory from "@/pages/subCategory.vue";
import product from "@/pages/product.vue";
import vendor from "@/pages/vendor.vue";
import vendorHoliday from "@/pages/vendorHoliday.vue";
import brand from "@/pages/brand.vue";
import tags from "@/pages/tags.vue";
import productTagMapping from "@/pages/productTagMapping.vue";
import fvStickers from "@/pages/fvStickers.vue";
import productStickers from "@/pages/productStickers.vue";


import { routeGuard } from './guard';
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/',
    name: 'Home',
    beforeEnter: routeGuard,
    component: Home
  },

  //sideBar Page routes,
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/category',
    name: 'category-page',
    component: CategoryPage,
  },
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/subCategory',
    name: 'subCategory',
    component: subCategory,
  },
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/product',
    name: 'product-page',
    component: product,
  },
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/vendor',
    name: 'vendor-page',
    component: vendor,
  },
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/vendorHoliday',
    name: 'vendor-holiday-page',
    component: vendorHoliday,
  },
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/brand',
    name: 'brand-page',
    component: brand,
  },
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/tags',
    name: 'tags-page',
    component: tags,
  },
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/productTagMapping',
    name: 'product-tag-mapping-page',
    component: productTagMapping,
  },
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/fvStickers',
    name: 'fvStickers',
    component: fvStickers,
  },
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/productStickers',
    name: 'product-stickers',
    component: productStickers,
  },



]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router


I might think there's some issue with how I defined the route but not sure about that.
I have tried these already but not working

 not working even though its connected
router-view content not rendering

Edit 1: Vue devtool image added
While going to the homepage, I got this in vue dev tools


What is getCompany doing? Is it properly generating the path as expected? Also, what do you see in your Vue devtools, routes tab, does everything seem fine? What if you try to navigate to one of those routes with something more simple and hard-coded like a <button @click="$router.push">? What do you have above the Home.vue? Does the Vue devtools show you the sidebar on the other page you're going to? How do you import the sidebar on that given page? Can we have an example of the given page? new VueRouter is using the vue-router v3, which is for Vue2. While createRouter is for

vue-router v4, for Vue3. Hence the first solution tried does not apply to your use-case. Not sure about the second one but it is a bit too old anyway to be relevant. I recommend you try to answer a few questions I have above. Then, try to reproduce the error with vue-router v3 in a [repro] locally on your machine. That way, you can then share it with us. The issue is probably not very difficult to solve here, mostly configuration and devtools usage to narrow it down. Also removing some stuff to keep it minimal might help a lot too.

getCompany is returning companyid which is 99 ( checked it with giving hardcoded value too). Attached the screenshot of what I am getting on Vue devtools.
Does the Vue devtools show you the sidebar on the other page you're going to? Ans - NO;
How do you import the sidebar on that given page?
Ans - NOT IMPORTING IT, simply wanted it to rendered through  else I had to define the navigate route function to all the pages;

You have a router-view component in App.vue which is the root router-view for all your routes.  This means your routes, /company/:company_id/, /company/:company_id/subCategory, etc. all load into this router-view unless you specify otherwise.
For nested routes (router-view inside another router-view) you need to use the children route property:
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/company/:company_id/',
    name: 'Home',
    beforeEnter: routeGuard,
    component: Home,
    //sideBar Page routes
    children: [
      {
        path: 'category',
        name: 'category-page',
        component: CategoryPage,
      },
      {
        path: 'subCategory',
        name: 'subCategory',
        component: subCategory,
      },
      ...
    ]
  },




I want to add both default path also to Category Component. like I tried this
    `path: '/company/:company_id/category' || '/company/:company_id',`

But doesn't work
